# Dynamically Add Fields to Hibernate Entity at Runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic

I have an application with custom fields - users are basically able to define a custom field by selecting a type for the field and giving it a name. The custom fields are then presented as being part of an entity and data given to these fields is saved to my database. In most circumstances, I've been able to handle these programmatically and through the normal hibernate mappings (ie, @OneToMany annotated collection) without a problem. I'm currently faced with a problem, however. We'd like to have these custom fields and their values used for real-time reporting of the "parent" entities. Custom field values are mapped as collections inside the parent entities, but I need them flat for reporting purposes. I have created a view that provides exactly what I need from the SQL side of things - [I followed this example to add dynamic pivoting and the resulting query is precisely how I'd like to display my information](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/). Not the following images, of course, but that's essentially the output I have.

[image: pivot1]

[image: pivot2]

The view returns a completely dynamic number of columns, each named for a custom field and populated with the relevant data for that row.

The problem is that I now have no idea how to retrieve this information with Hibernate.

I found documentation for updating the PersistentClass by getting the ClassMappings from the Hibernate Configuration:

[Manipulating metadata at runtime](http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/domain-models-and-metadata-hibernate/)

```
//Get the existing mapping for AgreementsGrid from Configuration
PersistentClass gridMapping = configuration.getClassMapping(AgreementsGrid.class.getName());

//Define new Column
Column column = new Column();
column.setName("ESTIMATED_COST_OVERRUNS");
column.setNullable(true);
column.setUnique(false);
gridMapping.getTable().addColumn(column);

//Wrap the column in a value
SimpleValue value = new SimpleValue();
value.setTable(gridMapping.getTable());
value.setTypeName("string");
value.addColumn(column);

//Define new property for the AgreementsGrid class
Property prop = new Property();
prop.setValue(value);
prop.setName("customField1");
prop.setNodeName(prop.getName());
gridMapping.addProperty(prop);

//Build a new session factory for the new mapping
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

I've only just realized that this is for Hibernate 3 & 4, and isn't even possible in Hibernate 5 (I'm using 5.2.18).

So, I'm trying to figure out how to handle this in Hibernate 5. I have a base entity mapped to a view, and at runtime I need to be able to dynamically add "fields" to it, so that my DAOs can dynamically filter the information and handle sorts/grouping.

Here is the entity I have for my view:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AGREEMENTS_GRID")
public class AgreementsGrid implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer entityId;
    @Column(name="ENTITY_ID")
    @Id
    public Integer getEntityId() {
        return this.entityId;
    }
    public void setEntityId(Integer entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    private Agreements agreement;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AGREEMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    public Agreements getAgreement() {
        return this.agreement;
    }
    public void setAgreement(Agreements agreement) {
        this.agreement= agreement;
    }

    private BigDecimal expenditure;
    @Column(name = "EXPENDITURE", nullable = true, precision = 22, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getExpenditure() {
        return this.expenditure;
    }
    public void setExpenditure(BigDecimal expenditure) {
        this.expenditure = expenditure;
    }

    /*
     * Dynamic fields would theoretically go here and look like this,
     * for a custom field of type CURRENCY named 'Estimated Cost Overruns'
     */
    /*
    private BigDecimal customField1;
    @Column(name = "ESTIMATED_COST_OVERRUNS", nullable = true, precision = 22, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getCustomField1() {
        return this.customField1;
    }
    public void setCustomField1(BigDecimal customField1) {
        this.customField1 = customField1;
    }
    */

 }
```

Just to be clear, I cannot map these fields at compile time. They are purely custom and are defined entirely by users. At runtime, I will be able to know what custom fields do exist, so I would be able to loop through them and add them (as I hoped to do with the add column seen above), but I cannot know before deployment. The custom fields are also subject to change any moment.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Map<String, String>` and a join table.

Comment: What exactly what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

For Hibernate 5 you should build MetaData via RegistryService, add property, then build SessionFactory via **MetaData** ([Bootstrap native metadata](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native-metadata)). Something like this:

```
public SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder) {    
  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
  registryBuilder.applySettings(sessionFactoryBuilder.getProperties());
  Metadata metaData = getMetadataSources().buildMetadata(registryBuilder.build());

  PersistentClass gridMapping = metaData.getEntityBinding(AgreementsGrid.class.getName());

  Column column = new Column();
  ...
  Property prop = new Property();
  ...
  gridMapping.addProperty(prop);

  SessionFactory sessionFactory = metaData.buildSessionFactory();
  return sessionFactory;
}
```